# Configure Engagement Split after activating a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In an activated journey an Engagement Split Decision of "Click" was selected for a previous email but no specific links were selected to monitor. Would the contacts continue to go down the "yes" branch if they clicked anywhere within the email? Or, are the links to monitor required to be selected even though "Click" for the particular message was selected?

Also, would there be a need for another version of the journey if the links should be selected and would the original contacts enter the "Click" path if within the 10 days of the wait period before the Engagement Split Decision is determined?

Please see image below.[image: JourneyBuilder Engagement Split]

Comment: Hey CPINK - did i manage to answer your question, or was there something else at play? If not, please mark as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

The click engagement has three states:

- Monitor all
- Monitor specific links
- Monitor none (haven't been able to verify this option)

It seems that you have inadvertently selected the last option. If so, it means that everybody will essentially pass down the no path. If it's just a visualization aspect and you've actually selected monitor all (which would seem logical to me, as you would need to select at least 1 link for it to save), they will all pass down the yes branch.

You would need to create a new version to correct this.

In addition, those that are on version 1, will stay there. They cannot be moved to version 2.

Answer (score 0):

If the Engagement Splits are not configured (your example) the population goes through the NO branch.

We just dealt with the same scenario a few weeks ago.

Hope this helps.

Thanks